# How to index Desktop in Windows 11 where Desktop is part of OneDrive

Tags: windows, windows-11, onedrive, windows-search, search-indexing

Since I use OneDrive and `Desktop` is part of my OneDrive Backup folders, it's located at `%UserProfile%\OneDrive\Desktop`

I can't find the `OneDrive` directory and hence can't find `Desktop` to index; how do I get `Desktop` indexed?

- I am running Windows 11 Home v22H2 b22621.2715
- *Settings* → *Privacy & Security* → *Classic* → *Customize Search Locations* 
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: OneDrive appears to be auto-indexed and hasn't been selectable through _Indexing Options_ since 2018. Why do you believe it's not being indexed and from within what part of the GUI are you searching _(e.g. Start Menu, Explorer, or Search)_?

Comment: @JW0914 I am searching through start menu. Control-Esc & type out the name of the file. Used to work in Windows 10

Comment: Are you using a third-party Start Menu _(e.g. Stardock Start11)_? If not, searching for a document that's only within my `OneDrive` does show in the Start Menu search, as well as in Explorer search, and Taskbar Search

Comment: @JW0914 - no it's a fresh machine from a week back

Answer (score 1):

I had some major issues with Windows Search in some folders and mostly, my OneDrive.

***I found a solution to OneDrive not being included as part of Windows Search Index.***   You can keep your files in the cloud, and where they are now, and this still works.

For any folder you want to be part of Windows Search Index, OneDrive folders included...  you need to change the permissions, and possibly ownership.  I changed all my searchable folders to add "Everyone", with "full control".

Your computer may choke on doing this to one very large OneDrive folder and if it does, just do one smaller folder at a time.

You'll immediately see that those folders are now searchable via your Windows key, and typing a few letters.

NOTE that you still won't see the OneDrive folder as an selectable option under Windows Search options!  It doesn't matter.   Windows will index it regardless.    As for that "Don't use the index when searching in file folders for system files..." check box found under "File Explorer Options" (found only from a File Explorer window)...  it doesn't seem to make a difference for me.  I have it UNCHECKED and it works great.  Changing the folder permissions did make a difference tho.

ANOTHER NOTE...   I did make sure Windows was logged into my account that is the same as my OneDrive folder.  But I'm not sure that helped.   Changing permissions did.

**Here's the path to changing the PERMISSIONS for a folder:**

RIGHT click the folder and go to Properties - Security tab - Edit (under Group or user names) - Add - Advanced (button at the bottom left) - Find Now (on the right side) - in the list find and double-click "Everyone" - Press OK - Click on Everyone - click on the Full Control and Modify check boxes below - click ok.

IF YOU GET ERRORS trying to change permissions, just tap to continue anyway. If you are desperate to just get it done, you have to change the OWNERSHIP of that folder.  I changed it, like the files, to 'everyone' (yes, some will argue that unsafe to do, but hey, it's my PC and I'm ok with that)

**Here's the path to changing OWNERSHIP of your files and folders:**

Right click the folder and go to Properties - Security tab - click Advanced near the bottom - at the very top will show Name:  xxxx   and Owner:  xxx    CLICK on the blue highlighted "Change" - Advanced - Find Now - double-click on Everyone in the list below - Press OK - check the box at the top for "Replace owner on subcontainers and object" - Press OK ... and away it goes.   THEN try to change security for all files and folder.   It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put USERS  into the location in Indexing Locations. It is not there right now, but if you add the USERS folder (not just the One Drive folder) it will index.

See my screen shot below.

Remember that when you add USERS to allow time to rebuild the index.

My One Drive folder is in USERS (like you show in your question) and it is indexed for fast searching.

[image: Windows Index]

Comment: But it doesn't show OneDrive directory inside "Users". Also I don't want everything indexed inside \users\myuser but only \users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop

Comment: @user93353 -Shouldn’t be required to specifically indicate you want to index that folder as by default everything is indexed.

Comment: Indexing is design to include USERS and only index what it is supposed to. That is built into the design. So use as designed. I know my index is working correctly because of the large number indexed (consistent to before One Drive).

Comment: @Ramhound - there are 2 options - classic & everything - in everything the whole disk is indexed but I think classic allows to choose which folders but I can't choose Desktop because it's part of OneDrive folder

Comment: I do not suggest indexing the whole disk.  But USERS should be selectable - you showed USERS in your indexed locations screen. If your system is working properly it will show.

Comment: I can select users, but I don't want the whole Users to be indexed. I want only Desktop in Users to the indexed

Comment: The index for USERS will only index appropriate items. You cannot split up USERS to index only pieces of it. That does not work in my long experience with Windows Index. An index is just that - an index.  Nothing otherwise special about it.

Comment: It does allow you to selectively choose directories & sub-directories from under USERS but desktop isn't there so I can't selectively choose it

Comment: That is because of the index design and what may be in pieces that cannot be indexed properly.

Comment: You are better off and father ahead just to index USERS.  No harm comes from doing that and no performance hit comes from doing that.

Comment: @John OneDrive hasn't been selectable in _Indexing_ since v1709 and was [removed](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/onedrive-no-longer-in-list-of-folders-to-index-in/606ae7c0-8ca8-4c0e-9263-88984b798fce) in 2018 - it is auto-indexed by default since 2018, but will not show within _Indexing_ options. `Users` can be customized to only include specific directories within it, but not specific files, only specific extensions via _Advanced_ → _File Types_

Comment: But if you select USERS, the One Drive folders will be indexed. I am doing this here in Windows 11 .  Of course I am talking about the local files, not the cloud files.

Comment: @John To determine that for sure, Microsoft Learn would need to be consulted, or `Users` could be removed, indexing rebuilt, then test, as `OneDrive` can be stored anywhere, but is defaulted to `%UserProfile%\OneDrive`. _(For example, I store `OneDrive` on a separate drive since it's >500GB in size, and I would test the above, but I have so much indexed, it takes forever to rebuild)_

Comment: On a fast local drive with about 100 GB of files and documents  Indexing works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Run
*Settings > Privacy & security > Search permissions*
and ensure that the options under "Cloud content search" are enabled.
You might also take a look at what's found when clicking on
"Manage accounts used by other apps on this device".

[image]

If this doesn't help, the free
[Everything from voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/)
can index OneDrive.

See [this post](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10601)
for the required settings of Everything.